# efficient 16 bit hash

Tags: hash

I'm looking for a way to make a 16bit ID out of approx 100 bits of data. The solution should be easy to implement, or should already be implemented in c++, should be quick to evaluate, and most importantly the values of the ID should be uniformly distributed, which is to say that one value should not have a higher chance to be taken than another.

Comment: possible duplicate of [efficient 16 bit checksum](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16220/efficient-16-bit-checksum)

Comment: No it's not. I asked the two questions, they're different. In here, I want a ID, not a checksum. And the data length is not the same, in one case it's a hundred bits, in another it's up to tens of thousands.

Comment: Hi bob - the way this, and your associated question, are written don't seem very on-topic here, where we aim to look for the most appropriate security solution/process etc for a security professional. Implementation of a piece of code should probably be in SO. Can you clarify the question - we can then see if it should be migrated in order to get answers useful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [the question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16220/ofefficient-16-bit-checksum) Rook linked, 16bits is very very weak, reducing 100bits to 16 leads to ~6 possible collisions per hash.

Are you sure you need a hash for that ? 16bits is enough to be stored in an integer and could simply be incremented if you just need a way to identify an object (limited to 65536).

If nevertheless you want to use an hash function, you could try to use something very simple such as [Pearson hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_hashing) that will produce a 8bit hash.

```
h := 0
for each c in C loop
  index := h xor c
  h := T[index]
end loop
return h
```

I quote Wikipedia, the advantages of this function are :

- It is extremely simple.
- It executes quickly on resource-limited processors.
- There is no simple class of inputs for which collisions (identical outputs) are especially likely.
- Given a small, privileged set of inputs (e.g., reserved words for a compiler), the permutation table can be adjusted so that those inputs yield distinct hash values, producing what is called a perfect hash function.

The adaptation to 16bits shouldn't be too hard. For example, [this page](http://bannister.us/weblog/2009/08/18/extending-the-pearson-hash-function-to-larger-values/) gives an example of adaptation but I think the author forget to change the size of the table to 65535, the code would be :

```
static unsigned short T[] = {
    // The values 0..65535 shuffled into random order.
};

static inline unsigned hashOf(unsigned h,const char* s) {
    for (int c = *s++; c; c = *s++) {
        h = T[h ^ (65535 & c)];
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm sure I need that, and incrementing an int is not enough because I need two hashes of the same value, produced at different times, to produce the same result. Thanks for your answer. Where can I find or how to generate the table used in the algorithm ?

Comment: Here ( https://github.com/dpree/pearson-hashing/blob/11bb69afd7b8184aa618065d4d8f6e027cd7e586/lib/pearson-hashing.rb ) you have an example of ruby code with a permutation table that also implement de 16bits hashing. The generation of perfect lookup table seems to be a common problem, you should find other examples on internet. Maybe also useful info : http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/pearsonshash.html